# How to rewrite a function such that integer division is applied before multiplication

Tags: integers, rounding

Given the following function

$$
f(x,y) = (x \cdot y + 999)\; \text{div} \; 1000
$$

where $x \in \{0, 1, 2, \dots, 2^{63}-1\}$, $y \in \{1, 2, 3, \dots, 500\}$, and the div operator is defined to round down, i.e. $a\;\text{div}\;b \;\colon= \lfloor a / b \rfloor$, is there a way to rewrite the expression such that the div operator is applied before the multiplication?

Let's say $y=20$. Then I expect the function to output the following values:

```
f(0, y) = 0
f(x, y) = 1  // for x in  1 to  50
f(x, y) = 2  // for x in 51 to 100
...
```

My problem is that I'm writing a program and the product $x\cdot y$ can become greater than $2^{63}-1$ and therefore overflow. However, the value of the whole expression is guaranteed to be less than this value, as it can approximately be

$$
(2^{63}-1)\cdot 500/1000 + 999/1000 \approx 2^{63} \cdot 0.5 + 1 \approx 2^{62}
$$
at maximum. I tried to find some equivalence relation that involves products, divisions, and floor functions but couldn't find one that matches my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The +999 will make the result go up by 1 *except* when xy is exactly 0 mod 1000.

It's easy to calculate xy mod 1000 without overflow, as (x mod 1000)*(y mod 1000). So we have two cases:

- xy = 0 mod 1000: then your f(x,y) is the same as xy div 1000.
- xy != 0 mod 1000: then your f(x,y) is the same as (xy div 1000) + 1

So we can focus on just calculating xy div 1000.

The easiest thing is probably to long divide x by 1000. Let's say

$x = 1000a + r$

Of course $a,r$ are easy to calculate as $x\ \mathrm{div}\ 1000$ and $x\ \mathrm{mod}\ 1000$. Then

$xy = 1000ay + ry$

and therefore

$xy\ \mathrm{div}\ 1000 = ay + (ry\ \mathrm{div}\ 1000)$

No part of this expression will overflow if calculated straightforwardly.

Comment: Thank you very much, helped me a lot! One little mistake, though: `xy mod 1000 == ((x mod 1000)*(y mod 1000)) % 1000`.